# Audio recording through mic

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, audio-recording

I have a webpage on which users can record sound from their mic, and can download the recorded file.

So far I came to know about https://subinsb.com/html5-record-mic-voice.

But the problem is that the quality of recorded sound is very poor, not even able to hear it properly.

Is there any other option for doing this?

Comment: Please show us some code to help you.

Comment: right now i have used same code showing at above link

Comment: It is generally a good idea to add fundamental code fragments to your question. Just consider that the link will be broken in the future.